# PHP socket, different message length between sending and receiving

Tags: php, sockets, client-server, php-socket

I'm using a socket to transmit a compressed file, but the file size for sending are different from that of reception.

This is server:

```
<?php
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("socket_create() fallito: motivo: " . socket_strerror($this->sock) . "\n");
$ret = socket_bind($sock, "192.168.1.40", "9000") or die("socket_bind() fallito: motivo: " . socket_strerror($ret) . "\n");
$ret = socket_listen($this->sock) or die("socket_listen() fallito: motivo: " . socket_strerror($ret) . "\n");
while(true){
    if($buf = @socket_accept($this->sock)){
        echo "Call incoming\n";
        // Read lenght of file
        $lun = socket_read($buf, 1024);
        // Write ok
        socket_write($buf, "OkContinue", 1024) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
        // Read file of lenght $lun
        $lettura = socket_recv ($buf, $lun);
        // Write dimension
        echo "I need rec file of $lun size, but i rec: ".strlen($lettura)." size";
    }
}
?>
```

This is client:

```
<?php
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_connect($socket, "192.168.1.40", "9000") or die("Could not connect to server\n");  
socket_write($socket, strlen($message), 1024) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
while ($out = socket_read($socket, 1024)) {
    if ($out=="OkContinue"){
        socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
        echo "Send text of ".strlen($message)." size";
    }
}
?>
```

But this are 2 message, on client:

```
Send text of 3741477 size
```

And this is on server:

```
Call incoming
I need rec file of 3741477 size, but i rec: 82536 size
```

So why even though the protocol is TCP, you lose the data that is not retransmitted? What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the PHP pages of `socket_write`

> socket_write() does not necessarily write all bytes from the given
>   buffer. It's valid that, depending on the network buffers etc., only a
>   certain amount of data, even one byte, is written though your buffer
>   is greater. You have to watch out so you don't unintentionally forget
>   to transmit the rest of your data.

About the `socket_read` it could be possible you have to call it many times and concat the chunks of data until no more data to read is present